# React native SVG onTouch functions vs onResponder functions

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg

I am creating a mobile app with image editor. Right now I am using react native svg to draw lines on the image. I am wondering which built in gestures functions of SVG are more efficient, is it the onTouch functions (onTouchStart, onTouchMove, onTouchEnd) or the responder functions (onResponderGrant, onResponderMove, onResponderEnd)? Or should I use the PanResponder component of react native?